# Second time I create a fragment, views in fragment overlap with each other

Tags: xml, kotlin, view, fragment

Basically, I have one activity with several fragments. The first time I inflate the first fragment (Recipe List Fragment), It displays just fine. Spinner layout is visible on below of action bar. But once I selected an item in recyclerview and replace current fragment with another (Recipe details fragment), spinner gets tucked below action bar. This behaviour is constant when i pressed back button or create a new fragment.

**Layout for Recipe List Fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="16dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="16dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Recipe Type" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinnerRecipeType"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_anchor="@+id/app_bar"
                        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Layout for Main Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**This is how I get back to Recipe List fragment when I complete any operations (add, update, delete recipe) but the user can also back press.**

```
override fun redirectToRecipeList()
{
val manager = supportFragmentManager
val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
val fragmentList = RecipeList()
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragmentList)
transaction.addToBackStack(null)
transaction.commit()
}
```

This is the initial condition of the app

[image: This is the initial condition of the app]

This is how the app layout looks like once the second time I create Recipe List Fragment

[image: This is how the app layout looks like once the second time I create Recipe List Fragment]

Comment: why do you need a framelayout arround recyclerview? Why don't you create a linearlayout around the spinner and recyclerview, better just ditch everything and use a constraintlayout.

Comment: Hi mr @sergio, thank you for your suggestion. I just made the changes. The problem still persist